# Seekbar and Textview

Tags: android, textview, seekbar, marquee

I have a textview with a marquee effect on top of a Seekbar. 
Here is my seekbar listener.

```
seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            if (mediaPlayer != null && fromUser) {
                mediaPlayer.seekTo(progress * 1000);
            }
        }
    });
```

So when I seek with the seekbar the textview above with the marquee text refreshes with it. It doesn't happen with all phones.

The following lines were wrote for the textview only:

```
textView.setSelected(true);
textView.setText("aaaaa bbbbbbb ccccccc ddddddddd eeeeeeee ffffffff gggggggg");
```

Here is a portion of my xml:

```
    <SeekBar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/seekBar"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tog"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_marginRight="60dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"

        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:id="@+id/songName"
        android:text="Song Name"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp" />
```

I have no clue why the text view is being refreshed when I seek. How do I resolve this? I seek for HELP!! TIA

EDIT: I think it will be wise for me to mention again that the problem happens with some phones.

Complete code:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_section_one);

final ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.sec1list);
final TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.songName);
tduration = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.totalDuration);
telapsed = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.elapsedtime);
seekBar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
tg = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.tog);
textView.setSelected(true);
textView.setFocusable(false);
textView.setText("aaaaa bbbbbbb ccccccc ddddddddd eeeeeeee ffffffff gggggggg");
textView.setText("Tobu bhoy nei maa amra protibad korte jani");

// Check whether we're recreating a previously destroyed instance

Log.d("TAG", "Going to check whether Music is playing");
Log.d("TAG", "Player Status " + mediaPlayer.isPlaying() + " Saved Instatus ");
if(notificationManager!= null){
    notificationManager.cancelAll();
}
if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
    Log.d("TAG", "Music is playing at time " + mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
    handlerTIme();
    setNotification();
    tg.setChecked(true);
}


tg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(mediaPlayer != null && !mediaPlayer.isPlaying() && POSITION!=-1) {
            playMedia();
            Log.d("TAG", "Played " + mediaPlayer.isPlaying());
        } else if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mediaPlayer.pause();
            notificationManager.cancelAll();
            tg.setChecked(false);
            Log.d("TAG", "Paused " + mediaPlayer.isPlaying());
        } else if (POSITION == -1 && !mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            tg.setChecked(false);
            Log.d("TAG", "POSITION -1");
        }
    }
});

seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        if (mediaPlayer != null && fromUser) {
            mediaPlayer.seekTo(progress * 1000);
        }
    }
});

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1,  values);


// Assign adapter to ListView
listView.setAdapter(adapter);

listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        textView.setText(values[position]);
        textView.setSelected(true);

        POSITION = position;
        tg.setChecked(true);
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            notificationManager.cancelAll();

        }

        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(SectionOne.this, songIds[position]);
        seekBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration()/1000);
        Log.d("TAG", "Duration" + mediaPlayer.getDuration());
        playMedia();
        handlerTIme();


    }


});
}

private void handlerTIme() {
Log.d("TAG","Inside the handler");
int seconds = (int) (mediaPlayer.getDuration() / 1000) % 60 ;
int minutes = (int) ((mediaPlayer.getDuration() / (1000*60)) % 60);
tduration.setText(Integer.toString(minutes) + ":" + Integer.toString(seconds));
SectionOne.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            int mCurrentPosition = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() / 1000;
            seekBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration() / 1000);
            seekBar.setProgress(mCurrentPosition);
            int seconds = (int) (mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() / 1000) % 60;
            int minutes = (int) ((mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() / (1000 * 60)) % 60);
            if (minutes < 10) {
                min = "0" + Integer.toString(minutes);
            } else {
                min = Integer.toString(minutes);
            }
            if (seconds < 10) {
                sec = "0" + Integer.toString(seconds);
            } else {
                sec = Integer.toString(seconds);
            }

            telapsed.setText(min + ":" + sec);
        }
        mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    }
});
}

private void playMedia(){
mediaPlayer.start();
setNotification();
}

public void setNotification(){
String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);

notification = new Notification(R.drawable.aa1, null, System.currentTimeMillis());

RemoteViews notificationView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.controller);

//the intent that is started when the notification is clicked (works)
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
notification.contentView = notificationView;
notification.contentIntent = pendingNotificationIntent;
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
notificationManager.notify(1, notification);

}
```

XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.eatl.shadhinotamusic.SectionOne"
    android:background="#fbfaf5">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:background="@drawable/aa1"
        android:id="@+id/sec1head"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dp" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/sec1list"
        android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/bottomseconegradient"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"

            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:id="@+id/songName"
            android:text="Song Name"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tog"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">

        </RelativeLayout>


        <ToggleButton
           android:layout_width="50dp"
           android:layout_height="50dp"
           android:textOff=""
           android:textOn=""
           android:background="@drawable/toggle"
           android:id="@+id/tog"
           android:checked="false"
           android:layout_centerVertical="true"
           android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
           android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:background="@drawable/aa1"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:id="@+id/totalDuration"
            android:layout_below="@+id/seekBar"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/seekBar"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/seekBar" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:id="@+id/elapsedtime"
            android:layout_below="@+id/seekBar"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/songName"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/songName" />

        <SeekBar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/seekBar"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/relativeLayout"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/relativeLayout"
            android:layout_marginRight="60dp" />


    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Some text will come here regarding the songs and the artists may be and then blablabla but not so long that it screws up the view"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/sec1head"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/sec1head"
        android:layout_margin="5dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: pls put complete code, Not enough information to track it..

Comment: :) Please see the edit. Thanks

Comment: <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:id="@+id/totalDuration"
            android:layout_below="@+id/seekBar"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/seekBar"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/seekBar" />

Comment: its not possible for android to put a view at the right of and below of some view at the same time, remove  android:layout_alignRight="@+id/seekBar"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/seekBar" from the above textview